# Mathematica error in vector element access

Tags: vector

I have the following code, but Mathematica insists that `xj` is not a symbol! How may I fix that?

```
n={5,10,20};
Subscript[x, 1]=Table[0,{Subscript[n, [[1]]]+1}];
Subscript[x, 2]=Table[0,{Subscript[n, [[2]]]+1}];
Subscript[x, 3]=Table[0,{Subscript[n, [[3]]]+1}];
For[j=1,j<=3,j++,
    For[i=0,i<=Subscript[n, [[j]]],i++,
        Subscript[x, j][[i+1]]=i/Subscript[n, [[j]]]; 
   ];
];
```

and the error is

```
Set::setps: Subscript[x, j] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
Set::setps: Subscript[x, j] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
Set::setps: Subscript[x, j] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
General::stop: Further output of Set::setps will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

I want to do this,

We have three vectors such as $x_1$,$x_2$ and $x_3$ with length $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$ respectively. Let $n=\{n_1, n_2, n_3\}$. I want to calculate $x_i = \frac{i}{n_j}$, $i=0,\ldots,n_j$ which $j=1,2,3$. I want to express it mathematically as possible as it can be!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please revise your question so that the code can be copied from it into Mathematica.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you, I have included the main file, please check.

Comment: Please add the code to the question. A link is inconvenient. A simple remedy is not to use subscripts (fancy typesetting is sometimes better avoided).

Comment: please no attachments. They can contain viruses. No one know what they are downloading here. Also, The code should be pasted here in text, so the question will be valid after the attachment is gone.

Comment: Related: Point 2 of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Operators without Built-in Meanings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html), `Subscript[x,y]` is an operator, not a symbol.

```
Subscript[x, 1] = Table[0, {i, 3}];
?Subscript[x,1]

Information::nomatch: No symbol matching Subscript[x,1] found. >>
```

Thus, you cannot apply `Part` to it, because `Part` applies only to symbols.  This is not associate with your nested `For` loops and can be obtained simply from

```
Subscript[x, 1][[2]] = 2

Set::setps: Subscript[x, 1] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
```

An admittedly inelegant alternative is

```
For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
For[i = 0, i <= n[[j]], i++, y[[j, i + 1]] = i/n[[j]] ]];
y
```

Comment: Actually I don't get it! What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I just appended an ugly but functional alternative to my Answer.  There may be better alternatives.

Comment: @NoMan Don't use `Subscripts[]`

Comment: It's also not optimal! anyways, Thanks.

Comment: @belisarius What is the better alternative, and what do I have to do?

Comment: @NoMan The problem to answer that is that your code does nothing, and I can't foresee your intentions. So, how to answer what you should do if I don't know what you want to do?

Comment: @NoMan Here is one way. n = {5,10,20}; x = {Table[0,{n[[1]]+1}], Table[0,{n[[2]]+1}], Table[0,{n[[3]]+1}]}; For[j=1,j<=3,j++, For[i=0,i<=n[[j]],i++, x[[j,i+1]] = i/n[[j]] ]; ]; and here is a MUCH simpler way n = {5,10,20};
x = Map[Range[0,#]/# &, n] Scrape, paste and test that carefully

Comment: @Bill Thank you very much, you solved my problem!

Comment: @NoMan `For` loops, like `Do` loops, print no output.  To see the results, print `y`.  Also, I revised my Answer to eliminate all subscripts.